# $L^1$ norm for product of cosines

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, trigonometric-integrals

Let $k$ be an integer and consider the function
$$
f(t)=\prod_{i=1}^{k} \cos(3^{i-1}\pi t).
$$
I'm interested in finding bounds for $\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt$ in terms of $k$. The first idea that comes to mind is using Hölder's inequality:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| dt \le \prod_{i=1}^{k} \bigg(\int_{0}^{1}|\cos(3^{i-1}\pi t)|^k dt \bigg)^{\frac{1}{k}}
$$
Now, using the periodicity of $|\cos(3^{i-1}\pi t)|$, note that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|\cos(3^{i-1}\pi t)|^k dt =\int_{0}^{1}|\cos(\pi t)|^k dt, 
$$
so that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|dt \le \int_{0}^{1}|\cos(\pi t)|^k dt,
$$
and I'm sure there should be some results for the moments of cosine. However, computationally this doesn't seem like a good bound. Is there a better way to do this? The reason I'm interested in this function is because it appears in the context of the Fourier transform of a certain set of integers.

Comment: For integrals of $(\cos(\pi t))^k$ you can derive the recurrence relation by integration by parts $\pi^{-1}\sin(\pi x)'(\cos(\pi t))^{k-1}.$